# How to specify SSL/TLS cipher suites on Java LDAP connection?

Tags: java, ssl, jndi, jsse

```
LdapContext ctx = null;
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable <String, String>();
try{

    env.clear();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "url");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
    env.put("java.naming.security.ssl.ciphers", "SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5");
    ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
} catch(NamingException nex) {

// error handling
}
```

I added a cipher to be included but I dont see it in the list of supported ciphers offered in my client's hello message, it still send the default cipher suites......

Comment: Where did you find `java.naming.security.ssl.ciphers`? I can't find any evidence that it even exists.

Comment: I find it in this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489403/how-to-specify-ssl-tls-version-on-java-ldap-connection/42800339#42800339

Comment: but it doesn't work, do you have some solution？

Comment: and here also occurs:http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/IBMDS/guide322/en_US/HTML/Guide.html#Client Side Caching

Comment: You can't cite another StackOverflow question as evidence. The IBM document is over ten years old and applies specifically to the 'IBM JNDI LDAP Provider'. Not Sun's or Oracle's. Clearly they don't support it.

Comment: yeah, you are totally right. you meant that on LDAP connection can't specify the TLS cipher suites, right?

Comment: That's what it looks lke. You would have to specify your own socket factory and set them that way.

Comment: but on LDAP connection,it uses the Context to set the parameters,  it hasn't used the socket factory, so I don't know where to set them.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation? It clearly specifies how to set a socket factory.

Comment: thank you, EJP,  after refer to the documentation, I can specify the cipher suites through set a socket factory, but I met one new issue, could you give some advice? thanks a lot. I will submit a question in another link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848047/how-to-add-unsupported-cipher-suitesnot-included-in-the-default-cipher-suites