# How to enable cipher TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 in SSLEngine

Tags: java, android, openssl, tcpclient, sslengine

I am are trying to connect to server which supports cipher TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384. 
At client side i am using SSLengine with Conscrypt as Java security provider(JCE).

I tried to set the cipher in sslengine but was getting exception as :

```
IllegalArgumentException : cipherSuite TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 is not supported
```

I saw the conscrypt [doc](https://github.com/google/conscrypt/blob/master/CAPABILITIES.md) and didn't find the cipher that i want to enable in the supported list of ciphers.

I also tried to use basic sslengine without conscrypt JCE which by default use android packaged conscrypt implementation and invokes `NativeCrypto` which also throws the same exception as i was getting with conscrypt JCE because both uses same implementations.

Could anybody help me to set the desired cipher in SSLEngine or provide some guidance to how to achieve it?

Comment: What is the java version that you using ? does it having JCE unlimited strength jurisdiction policy files by default or have you add them ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848047/how-to-add-unsupported-cipher-suitesnot-included-in-the-default-cipher-suites, does this post answers your question